# How can I access a specific database in mongodb container using typescript?

Tags: database, typescript, mongodb

My connection code is this one

```js
const url = 'mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017';
const Connected=async()=>{
  
    await MongoClient.connect(url,(err, client) =>{
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected successfully to MongoDb server");
       
    })}
```

But I want to access a specific database called `test` an not just a connection to the server.

PS: I tried to add the database name after the connection string but it did not help.

Comment: Is this DB connecting successfully?

Comment: yes it does but i want to access a specific database, not just a server

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470